# Single Row Selection on Dynamically created html table row

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, ajax

I have created a dynamic table. this html table has data-binding and gets all the data from the database. I have a on-click row selection function using jquery but I think it only executes on a static table (hard-coded). Can someone help me to have a on-click single row selection on a dynamically created html table row .(it should be single row selection which means when the user clicks on other table row, the last selected row should be unselected.)

HTML

```
<table id="tblCases">
<thead > 
<tr>
<th>CASE KEY</th>
<th>DEPARTMENT CASE #</th>
<th>DEPARTMENT</th>
<th>CHARGE</th>
<th>LAB CASE #</th>
<th>INCIDENT REPORT DATE</th>
</tr>
</thead> 
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#tblCases tr.selectedRow{background-color: #56bff0;}
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'E****_L******_AjaxWS.asmx/GetRecentCases',
    dataType: "json",
    method: 'post',
    success: function (data) {
        var recentcasesTable = $('#tblCases tbody');
        recentcasesTable.empty();
        $(data).each(function (index, rcases) {
            recentcasesTable.append('<tr><td>' + rcases.CASE_KEY + '</td><td>'
                        + rcases.DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER + '</td><td>' + rcases.DEPARTMENT_NAME + '</td><td>' + rcases.CHARGE
                        + '</td><td>' + rcases.LAB_CASE + '</td><td>' + rcases.OFFENSE_DATE + '</td></tr>');
        });
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

JQUERY(my on-click row selection, it is working only on static table)

```
$('#tblCases tr').click(function () {
       $('#tblCases tr').removeClass('selectedRow');
       $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
   })
```

Comment: You should declare your "click" handler in your ajax success callback, after appending the new rows. So that your new rows also have click handler attached.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your "click" handler in your ajax success callback, after appending the new rows. So that your new rows also have click handler attached. Make sure you remove previous click handlers with "off"  to avoide duplicate handlers.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'E****_L******_AjaxWS.asmx/GetRecentCases',
dataType: "json",
method: 'post',
success: function (data) {
    var recentcasesTable = $('#tblCases tbody');
    recentcasesTable.empty();
    $(data).each(function (index, rcases) {
        recentcasesTable.append('<tr><td>' + rcases.CASE_KEY + '</td><td>'
                    + rcases.DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER + '</td><td>' + rcases.DEPARTMENT_NAME + '</td><td>' + rcases.CHARGE
                    + '</td><td>' + rcases.LAB_CASE + '</td><td>' + rcases.OFFENSE_DATE + '</td></tr>');           
    });

   $('#tblCases tr').off("click").on("click", function () {
     $('#tblCases tr').removeClass('selectedRow');
     $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
   });

},
error: function (err) {
    alert(err);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rebind jquery table row click after append new rows into table